# Working with Trello cards in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mylyn, trello

Is it possible to setup Trello as an Eclipse Mylyn task repository? Is there any existing connector or some other way to do it?

Answer (score 8):

[This excellent tutorial](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jvmJcCStE6QkJ0z5ASddc3fNmJwhJPOFN7X9-GLyabM/edit#heading=h.pexwc0odfm6n) explains how it may be done by using Web Template Connector along with the Trello REST API.

However, the regex pattern in #19 there isn't totally correct, and causes to some issues being skipped. It should be changed to this:

```
\"id\"[\x00-\x7F]+?\"idShort\":({Type}[0-9]+)[\x00-\x7F]+?\"name\":\"({Description}[\x00-\x7F]+?)\"[\x00-\x7F]+?\"shortLink\":\"({Id}[\x00-\x7F]+?)\"[\x00-\x7F]+?\"url\"
```

So that all user's cards will appear in the MyLyn repository.

Comment: I'm unsure why but the pattern from the doc works whereas yours doesn't!?

Comment: Fantastic solution! With idBoard: `\"id\"[\x00-\x7F]+?\"idBoard\":\"1234\"[\x00-\x7F]+?\"idShort\":({Type}[0-9]+)[\x00-\x7F]+?\"name\":\"({Description}[\x00-\x7F]+?)\"[\x00-\x7F]+?\"shortLink\":\"({Id}[\x00-\x7F]+?)\"[\x00-\x7F]+?\"url\"` set 1234 as your idBoard.

Answer (score 2):

Correct regexp to [tutorial](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jvmJcCStE6QkJ0z5ASddc3fNmJwhJPOFN7X9-GLyabM/edit#heading=h.pexwc0odfm6n). It supports labels of cards and cyrillic description.

All cards:

> \"id\".+?\"idShort\":({Type}[0-9]+).+?(?:\"idLabels\".+?)\"name\":\"({Description}.+?)\",.+?\"shortLink\":\"({Id}.+?)\".+?\"url\"

Cards of your BOARD_ID

> \"idBoard\":\"BOARD_ID\".+?\"idShort\":({Type}[0-9]+).+?(?:\"idLabels\".+?)\"name\":\"({Description}.+?)\",.+?\"shortLink\":\"({Id}.+?)\".+?\"url\"

Answer (score 2):

The regular expressions didn't work for me anymore. Instead I did this:

Create a new web template repository:

- Create a new web template repository
- Under additional settings, add the applicationkey and userkey parameter
- Under advanced configuration, add the task url `https://trello.com/c/`
- Leave the rest empty.

Create a new query:

- Go to the Task List view. Rightclick New -> Query
- Select the web template repository and name it after the board or however you like
- Add another parameter boardid.     You can get the board id from `https://trello.com/1/members/my?key={{trello_applicationkey}}&token={{trello_userkey}}`
- For Query URL use `https://api.trello.com/1/boards/${boardid}/cards?fields=name,shortLink&key=${applicationkey}&token=${userkey}`
- For Query Pattern use `"name":"({Description}.+?)","shortLink":"({Id}.+?)"`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers were giving all cards in the board, not just the ones assigned to me. I used the API search with filters to get what I needed.

**Create a new web template repository:**

- Under additional settings, add the applicationkey, userkey, memberid
  and boardname parameters
- Under advanced configuration, add the task url https://trello.com/c/
- Leave the rest empty.

**Create a new query:**

- Query URL:

  > https://api.trello.com/1/search?query=member:${memberid}%20board:${boardname}&card_fields=name,shortLink&cards_limit=100&key=${applicationkey}&token=${userkey}
- Query Pattern:

  > "name":"({Description}.+?)","shortLink":"({Id}.+?)"

More information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395252/trello-api-get-all-cards-assigned-to-a-user-on-a-specific-board/50418787#50418787).

Answer (score 0):

I had the error `Failed to parse RSS feed: "Invalid XML: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.`

After days of trying to fix this, I finally found that it was en encoding error.

In the **Web Repository Settings** under **Additional Settings** I selected `US-ASCII`.

I hope to help other people!