# Trello API: Get all Cards assigned to a user, on a specific board

Tags: api, trello

I'm trying to get all cards in a board assigned to a specific user, but the below returns all the cards in a board.

I did not find this solution anywhere; this is what I tried, and it returns cards assigned to all users:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/boards/${boardid}/cards?fields=name,shortLink&key=${applicationkey}&token=${userkey}
```

- ${boardid} = id of the board I want cards from
- ${applicationkey} = Trello Developer API Key
- ${userkey} = Trello User Token

Looks like a lot of people were able to do this, but there is no working documentation on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this (get all cards assigned to me), by using the Trello search API.

**Query URL (Cards assigned to a member):**

> https://api.trello.com/1/search?query=label:green%20member:${memberid}%20board:${boardname}%20sort:edited&card_fields=name,shortLink&cards_limit=100&key=${applicationkey}&token=${userkey}

**Query Pattern (regexp to read cards):**

> "name":"({Description}.+?)","shortLink":"({Id}.+?)"

**Parameters used:**

- ${applicationkey} =    Developer API Key
- ${userkey} = User Token
- ${boardname} = Actual name of the board in Trello
- ${memberid} = member id of the Trello user

**Get Developer API key and User Token:** [Click here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jvmJcCStE6QkJ0z5ASddc3fNmJwhJPOFN7X9-GLyabM)

**Get member id from here:**

> https://api.trello.com/1/search?query=is:open%20board:${boardname}%20sort:edited&card_fields=name,shortLink,member&cards_limit=100&key=APIKey&token=UserToken